# Reconciliation uses different number than entered

Tags: gnucash, reconciling

I'm doing a year-end reconciliation of one of my expense categories.  In the reconcile-setup window, I enter the amount `$36,387.59` for the ending balance:

[image]

However, the amount shown in the subsequent reconciliation window is different by several thousand dollars:

[image]

How is this "Ending Balance" being determined?  Is this expected behavior and there's something else going into computing this value, or is it a bug?

I'm using GnuCash 4.4-1 on Mac OS X 10.15.7.

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug at https://bugs.gnucash.org/show_bug.cgi?id=798144 .

Comment: The result of the Reconciliation process shows a difference between *your* number and *GnuCash's* number as at 31 December.  Either there are transactions that have not been entered into GnuCash (possible) or the GnuCash software is performing an incorrect calculation (possible, but unlikely) or your figure ( $36,387.59 ) is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In GnuCash the reconciliation feature is available for all accounts, regardless of the account type (whether it's an asset, liability, expense, etc).  With some accounts such as a bank savings account, credit card, etc (where you receive statements), there's an obvious benefit associated with reconciliation, because it brings your records into sync with those of the institution.  I preface with that information, because while the feature is sometimes needed and is always available, it is definitely not always required or even needed.  I have reconciled 'custom' accounts in the past, however I've never considered reconciling an expense account.

In any case, when I open reconciliation for one of my accounts, I see the same windows and fields you posted in your question, with the exception that the "Ending Balance" I enter in the "Reconcile Information" window matches the "Ending Balance" shown and used in calculations on the Reconciliation Window.  If I saw a mismatched value like that, I'd probably try restarting the application entirely and see if it behaves better after the restart.

Comment: Thanks Derek - I did try restarting the application, and even upgrading to the latest version of GnuCash.  Same problem.  As for why I want to reconcile this account, I prepare a category summary (not in GnuCash) for the year that I treat as my "statement", and I want to make sure it matches what I have in GnuCash.

Comment: Another angle to approach this would be to run an account report for the same time frame as the reconciliation, then copy or export that data to excel.  There you could do some manual calculations, using the same starting balance to create a running total, and see if the numbers match what is showing up in reconciliation.